# Add external product images to opencart

Tags: php, cdn, opencart

I need to use externally hosted product images as the product image for the desired items.
The Items are hosted on our CDN and the full URL is known.

All products are imported via a csv file which also includes those url's.

The problem is that after adding the product image url to both the image column of the product table and adding a row in the product_images table with this url, there still doesn't appear any product image.

Is there any option that needs to be set in order to upload products with images to opencart which I forgot to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in model/comon/image.php, there should be the resize function.
after declaring the function, just check to see if http:// is present at the begging of the url, if it is, dont attept to resize it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you modify the product code or just change the database? In OpenCart the images are resized by the tool/image model and the first check in the `resize()` function is that the file exists. Unless you've modified either the product model/view/controller and/or the tool/image model you're not going to be able to reference external images.